# Identity Matrix in symbolic Tensor Product

Tags: symbolic, tensors, algebra

I am trying to simplify symbolic tensor products. E.g.

```
$Assumptions = {Element[a1, Vectors[3, Reals]], 
  Element[a2, Vectors[3, Reals]], Element[b1, Vectors[3, Reals]], 
  Element[b2, Vectors[3, Reals]]};
    TensorReduce[
 TensorReduce[(TensorProduct[a2, b1] + 
     TensorProduct[a1, b1]).(TensorProduct[a1, a2])]]
```

This works fine but I would like to include the Identity Matrix. I.e.

```
(IdentityMatrix[3]+TensorProduct[a2, b1]).(TensorProduct[a1, a2])
```

But it gives me a dimension error.

To avoid confusion - the correct answer should of course be

```
a1\[TensorProduct]a2 + a1.b1 a1\[TensorProduct]a2
```

Instead of some weird 3x3 Matrix.

Would be very grateful for help!

Thanks!

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.
Why not choosing a meaningful name?

Comment: I have tried your code, and except for the missing closing parenthesis, I don't see any errors. Try to `Quit[]` the Kernel and executing your code again. Report the error you get in detail, What does *Mathematica* complain about?

Comment: For me, `(IdentityMatrix[3] + (TensorProduct[a2, b1]).(TensorProduct[a1, a2]))` works fine (running Mathematica 10.3/Windows), giving: `{{1 + a2 \[TensorProduct] b1 . a1 \[TensorProduct] a2, a2 \[TensorProduct] b1 . a1 \[TensorProduct] a2, a2 \[TensorProduct] b1 . a1 \[TensorProduct] a2}, 
 {a2 \[TensorProduct] b1 . a1 \[TensorProduct] a2, 1 + a2 \[TensorProduct] b1 . a1 \[TensorProduct] a2, a2 \[TensorProduct] b1 . a1 \[TensorProduct] a2}, 
 {a2 \[TensorProduct] b1 . a1 \[TensorProduct] a2, a2 \[TensorProduct] b1 . a1 \[TensorProduct] a2, 1 + a2 \[TensorProduct] b1 . a1 \[TensorProduct] a2}}`

Comment: So there is no "dimension error" from Mathematica, just a result that different from your expectations.

Comment: Correct - no error. It just doesn't treat the 3x3 matrix a1 \[TensorProduct] a2 and Identity as it should. Instead it writes it in every component.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the issued raised is not really a problem, but a misunderstanding of the result by the OP.